# Creating Custom Build Tasks in On Premise TFS2017?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I need to create custom build tasks in **TFS2017 ON PREMISE**. But in this microsoft link i can see only for VSTS(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts)
      Is it same for ON PREMISE & VSTS?
      Kindly help me to understand.

Comment: I don't see official docs but I know you can also develop for TFS 2017, did you try?

Comment: I dont know how to create? so that i have post it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the same for on-premise TFS and VSTS. Actually it's just an extension.

So, when the customized task is created ([Package your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts#step-4-package-your-extension)), it will generate a package (`*.vsix` file). For on-premise TFS 2017 you just need to upload the extension (`*.vsix` file) and install it for your collections. Please see [Install extensions for disconnected TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018#install-extensions-for-disconnected-tfs) for details.

To create a custom task you can follow the steps mentioned in this article: [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts)

And you can also reference the source codes of existing tasks stored on Github: [azure-pipelines-tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks)